# are there any pairs (x,y) such that x<<1 == y>>1?

Tags: binary, integer, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Are there any pairs (x,y) such that `z = x<<1` and `z == y>>1` where `x != y`?

Suppose we have x=0010 and y=1000
now if we shift left x by 1 and shift right y by 1
i.e, x<<1=0100 and y>>1=0100 so we have same result for both cases that is 0100

So are there any other pairs (x,y) giving same result z ?

If yes then **is there any equation to find out such pairs**?

Comment: `x=y=0` springs to mind..

Comment: you answer is not complete , do you know of any equation to find such pairs ?

Comment: Hence the comment. Generally speaking `x << 1 = y >> 1` <=> `x * 2 = floor(y / 2)` assuming positive infinite-precision integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@doynax observed:

```
x << 1 = y >> 1 <=> x * 2 = floor(y / 2)
```

Using floor(y/2)==y/2 if y is even; floor(y/2)=(y-1)/2 if y is odd, we get two equations:

```
(even y):   x * 2 = y / 2
(odd y):    x * 2 = (y-1)/2
```

Simplifying:

```
(even y)    x * 4 = y
(odd y)     x * 4 = y - 1  ==>   x * 4 + 1 = y
```

We remark that x * 2, and therefore x * 4, is an even number.
So any value of x has a corresponding y by the (even y) equation.

Likewise, x * 4 is even, and x * 4 + 1 is odd, so any
value of x has a corresponding y by the (odd y) equation.

So, these values are easy to generate.

1. Pick any X.
2. Both X*4 and X*4+1 are valid values for Y.
3. Z is X*2

This assumes infinite precision integers.  If you are working on a real CPU with an N bit word size, values of X>=2^N/4 won't work as a typical shift will lose bits off the top.

Answer (score 0):

Generally left shift of a number is (number^number_of_left_shifts) and right shift of a number is a (number/number_of_right_shifts)

you could try using the below equation,
x^1=y/2
y=2(x^1)

The above equation for only one left shift or right shift try substituting with the number_of_shifts you need

Comment: You can try with many examples by setting the x and y values which satisfy above equation

Comment: if I use the below values
x=10=01010
y=20=10100

x<<1=z1=10100
y>>1=z2=01010
here z1!=Z2
this equations is not completely correct in all cases

Comment: @AkhilChalla: then why did you "accept" this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the a,b values such that it satisfies below equation
a^2=b/4
b=4(a^2)